# How to log 415 errors in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My service is currently experiencing 415 errors, but I'm not getting any logs to find out what errors they are.

Will I be able to add logging in some kind of filter so that I can know what's going on?

```
@RequiresHttps
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> doAction(@NonNull @RequestBody CustomRequest[] requests) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 415 is happening inside spring mvc engine and it doesn't event reach your controller so that you can't really place the logs in our code (in `doAction` method for example).

Try to enable tomcat embedded access logs and you'll see the file with all the requests and return status. These are disabled by default so you should add the following into `application.properties` or yaml:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
```

There are some configurations / customizations you can do with that, you can read about them in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs)  for example